# So "ball" for PDEs is generally in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm getting confused with the use of the term "ball" in our courses and in some literature regarding PDEs. In some vector analysis courses ball and the notation $B(x,r)$ has been used for a ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

However, in PDEs (or particularly examples in PDEs) it seems that ball and $B(x,r)$ often (if not always?) refers to circles in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with center $x$ and radius $r$).

E.g. for the Poisson problem:

$$\nabla u = 1, u \in B(0,1)$$
$$u=0, u \in \partial B(0,1)$$

Would $B(0,1)$ refer to $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$ objects?

Comment: A sphere is just the outermost points of the ball. Just as a circle is just the outermost points of a disc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$B(x, r)$ refers to "All points in your space that are at most $r$ away from $x$". What dimension it has depends entirely on the dimension of the space where $x$ lives.

Comment: But surely the dimension matters e.g. in the Poisson BVP? Since then as a solution one'd have different amount of variables? Also I don't see any specifying of the dimensions in the Poisson BVPs that I've read.

Comment: Also, if the term "ball" is used with $B(x,r)$, then is it in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$ or where?

Comment: You would have to get the dimension of $B(x, r)$ from context. If $x$ is a point in $\Bbb R^2$, then $B(x, r)$ is a disc, and if $x$ is a point in $\Bbb R^3$, then $B(x, r)$ is a ball.

Comment: Also, if you want to speak in general terms, without implying dimension at all, $B$ is often referred to as a "ball".

Comment: @mavavilj What I'm trying to say is, $B$ is used for all dimensions, and you have to use other information available to you to decide which it is.

Answer (score 0):

In general $B(x,r)$ refers to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In your examples $(0,1)$ is not a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but a pair - origin point $(0,...,0)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (sometimes described by shortcut as $0$) and a radius $1$.